# Nested class property filter not working MVC5 NonFactor Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcgrid, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I have integrated NonFactors Grid in my Mvc5 application. Its filtering not working on inner class propery name however it works fine on its own properties. I have one class which is `User` and this contains `School` object onto it. This `School` class a `property` as `Name` and I bind it to model as below

```
columns.Add(model => model.School.Name).Titled("School Name");
columns.Add(model => model.UserName).Titled("User Name");
```

When I apply a filter on `User Name` it works perfectly fine but same is not working on `School Name`. Its giving error in `_Grid.cshtml` saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`'
Please refer below.

[image]

Can you please guide how to fix it?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding null check on column value solved the problem.

```
columns.Add(model => model.School == null ? null : model.School.Name).Titled("School Name").Filterable(true);
```